# flutter: how to display error message in Text widget instead of default error message

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two inputs and want to handle errors outside the form in a `Text()` widget.

if it's possible, I want to check for errors using validation and when there's an error instead of displaying it under the text input, I want a separate `Text()` widget to show the errors of both inputs.

like in this image:
NOTE: IMAGE FROM FIGMA DESIGN

[image]

my code:

```
Form(
            key: widget.formKey,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        child: Text(
                          !isRTL
                              ? '(${widget.product.packageQuantity}) ${widget.product.packingName}'
                              : '(${widget.product.packageQuantity}) ${widget.product.packingRtlName}',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                          decimal: true,
                          signed: true,
                        ),
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        autofocus: false,
                        onSaved: (newValue) => widget.onSavePQ(newValue!),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter some text';
                          }
                          if (int.parse(value) >
                              widget.product.packageQuantity) {
                            return 'Wrong Values';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 1,
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            fontSize: 0,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'PQ',
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        child: Text(
                          // '(${widget.product.unitQuantity}) ${context.loc.language}',
                          !isRTL
                              ? '(${widget.product.unitQuantity}) ${widget.product.unitName}'
                              : '(${widget.product.unitQuantity}) ${widget.product.unitRtlName}',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                          decimal: false,
                          signed: false,
                        ),
                        autofocus: false,
                        onSaved: (newValue) => widget.onSaveUQ(newValue!),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter some text';
                          }
                          if (int.parse(value) > widget.product.unitQuantity) {
                            return 'Wrong Values';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 1,
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            fontSize: 0,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'UQ',
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to handle the error separately by defining a String variable at the beginning of the widget and setting its value on validation. Once set you can use the value inside the Text() widget to get the required result.
Here is a demo code:

```
class newApp extends StatefulWidget {
 const newApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<newApp> createState() => _newAppState();
   }

   class _newAppState extends State<newApp> {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

     String? error1;  //define error1
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: TextFormField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              if(value=='2')
              {
                setState(() {
                error1="problem"; //set value of error1 in setState()
              });
              }
              else
              {
                setState(() {
                error1='no problem'; //set value of error1 in setState()
              });
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        if (error1=='problem') ...[
          Text(error1.toString()),  //use the value in setState()
        ],
        if (error1!='problem') ...[
          Text(''),   //can be changed to user specified code incase of no error
        ]
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
 }
```

I would suggest using Onchanged Instead of Validator as we have to use setState on every user interaction which creates a build error when used with the validator, so instead use OnChanged.